# JavaFX gradle depedency using Kotlin DSL but got unresolved reference for modules instead

Tags: javafx, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I tried to apply JavaFX plugin to `build.gradle.kts` as follows

```
plugins {
    java
    id("org.openjavafx.javafxplugin") version "0.0.5"
}

javafx {
    version = "12"
    modules("javafx.controls", "javafx.fxml")
}
```

but `modules()` does not refer to any function it says.
the output of build said something like

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public inline operator fun <T : Any, C : NamedDo...
```

how do I resolve this?

Comment: Getting started at [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#gradle) covers this (though not kotlin).

Comment: What if you use a more recent version of the plugin?